# Remove point outlines in scatter3d plot points

Tags: python, plotly

I am working on a python dash app. I have created a 3d scatter plot based on a dataframe `df`. The points on the plot all have white outlines, and when they are clustered tightly, the outlines make it look messy. Is there a way to remove the outlines?

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")

data = [
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=df[x_axis],
        y=df[y_axis],
        z=df[z_axis],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(size=df['size_col']),
    )
]

layout = go.Layout(
    scene=dict(xaxis={'title': 'x'},
               yaxis={'title': 'y'},
               zaxis={'title': 'z'}),
    margin={'l': 60, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 10},
    legend={'x': 0, 'y': 1},
    hovermode='closest'
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='simple-3d-scatter')
```

This is what it currently looks like for me: [3d scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc6xb.jpg)

It should be possible because when looking at https://plot.ly/python/3d-scatter-plots/#3d-scatter-plot-with-colorscaling, the plot does not have these white outlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marker objects have their own line attributes.

```
data = [
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=df[x_axis],
        y=df[y_axis],
        z=df[z_axis],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            size=df['size_col'],
            line=dict(width=0)
        ),
    )
]
```

Comment: Ah great, I was looking for something called outline, should've seen line. Thanks!